# How to handle Resource Lists type of questions

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should Genealogy.se allow “list” questions?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/should-genealogy-se-allow-list-questions)

I see some questions starting to come in asking "Where can I find...". These questions are going to generate multiple answers, each with a different resource. Is this a good fit for a Q&A site?

Yes - The best resource gets voted to the top

No - There is no definitive "Answer" to these types of questions.

How do we want to handle these in the private beta, how about when the site launches?

- [Where can I find Jewish Historical Information Pre WWII in Europe?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/115/what-are-good-sites-to-search-for-jewish-historical-information-pre-wwii-in-eu)
- [Finding Utah ancestor's parents after exhausting BMD records, census and newspapers?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/111/what-do-i-do-to-find-a-utah-ancestors-parents-when-i-have-exhausted-vital-stati)